# When resizing the iframe html got disturbed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have applied each and every js present on stack exchange but nothing goes right for me. My problem is when i use auto re size js it adjust itself but its html get disturbed. JS Code is below

```
    function autoResize(id){
var newheight;
var newwidth;

if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
    newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
}

document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";}
```

my HTML is

```
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
      <!-- Main row -->
       <div class="row">
        <iframe width="100%" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="margin-right:300px background: #FFFFFF;border:none" name="NewFrame1" frameborder="0"/></iframe>
    <!--  <iframe width="100%" height="200px" style="margin-right:300px background: #FFFFFF;border:none" id="iframe1" name="NewFrame1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>-->
      </div><!-- /.row (main row) -->

    </section><!-- /.content -->
  </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

and then i called my URL's like this

```
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="/Testing/Testing.DefineCompany?ActionID=CustomerForm" target="NewFrame1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" ></i> Add Company</a></li>
```

Please anyone who can help me :(. Stuck in this issue for days now.

Comment: The code for the function `resizeIFrame(this)` in the iframe onload is not included above. Also, the assignment statements for `newheight` and `newwidth` should probably not have a space between `document` and `.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollHeight is not the most reliable way of working out the height of an iFrame.

I would suggest trying out the iframe-resizer library, it has lots of options to deal with weird cases like this.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: ok i get that but my issue is when the page opens on the browser and suppose html is very long and if i select next page whose html is short it display the page with the width and height of longer html which i clicked first. Can you please help me on this that how can i refreshed that?

Comment: Use offsetHeight rather than scrollHeight. If the page has margins you'll need to add them to the returned figure.

Comment: can you give me an example please, it would be a great help for me as i am learning and new to bootstrap and all :)

Comment: newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;